# User Claims seem to be getting replaced somewhere along the pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, claims-based-identity

**Edit: If anyone has any clue how i can better ask or inform you guys about this problem please let me know.

So I am creating custom claims and trying to add them to my user. I see the claims in the User.Identity right after I add them and slightly down the line in the pipeline but by the time it gets to my Global.asax the User.Identity has lost all but one of my claims. I also think the user is changing from a claimsPrinciapl to a GenericPrincipal during the same time. I dont know if I am understanding this or explaining this very well. Not even sure what all code to post but I will post some below.

This is where my user is Authenticated and cookies and claims are create. Note i have been trying a lot of stuff so this might have some weird code:

```
    private AuthenticationResponse AuthenticateUserByService(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe)
    {
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator(AppInfo.AuthServiceAddress, AppInfo.ClientId, AppInfo.Secret);
        AppInfo.rememberMe = rememberMe;
        AuthenticationResponse response = auth.Authenticate(userName, password);
        if (response.IsError)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(response.ErrorDescription);
            return null;
        }

        if (response.AppUser == null)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("No error or user!  Unknown reason.");
            return null;
        }
        var cookieHelper = new Helpers.CookieHelper();
        //FormsAuthenticationTicket authtick = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, response.AppUser.Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(response.AppUser.ExpiresIn *2), true, response.AppUser.RefreshToken);
        var authtick = cookieHelper.CreateAuthTicket(response.AppUser, true);

        var authCookie = cookieHelper.CreateAuthCookie(authtick);
        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

        var tokenCookie = cookieHelper.CreateTokenCookie(response.AppUser, true);
        Response.Cookies.Add(tokenCookie);

        // If caching roles in userData field then extract
        string[] roles = response.AppUser.Permissions.Select(x => x.PermissionName).ToArray(); // = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });

        // Create the IIdentity instance
        IIdentity id = new FormsIdentity(authtick);

        var newIdent = new ClaimsIdentity(id);

        foreach (var item in roles)
        {
            newIdent.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item));
        }
        ClaimsPrincipal cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdent);           


        // Create the IPrinciple instance
        IPrincipal principal = cp; //new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = cp;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(cp);
        // Set the context user 
        HttpContext.User = principal;
        //IOwinContext context = Request.GetOwinContext();
        //var authManager = context.Authentication;
        //authManager.SignIn(newIdent);

        this.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, newIdent);


        return response;
```

In the above code, I can see my user and his claims right after I set the HttpContext.User.

Below is just me checking out the User to make sure it was successful:

```
   private AppUser AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe)
    {
        //bool userAuthenticated = false;
        AuthenticationResponse userAuthenticated = null;
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            userAuthenticated = AuthenticateUserByService(userName, password, rememberMe);
            var c = User.Identity;
            success = !userAuthenticated.IsError;
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

At one point the claims disappeared by the time I set c to the user.

And i figured this might be important so below is where i create my cookies and tickets:

```
internal class CookieHelper
{
    internal FormsAuthenticationTicket CreateAuthTicket(AppUser appUser, bool isPersistent)
    {
        return new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            appUser.Username,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((appUser.ExpiresIn * 2)),
            isPersistent,
            appUser.RefreshToken == null ? "" : appUser.RefreshToken,
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    }

    internal HttpCookie CreateAuthCookie(FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket)
    {
        // Encrypt the ticket.
        string encAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

        // Create the cookie.
        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encAuthTicket);
        authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;

        return authCookie;
    }

    internal HttpCookie CreateTokenCookie(AppUser appUser, bool isPersistent)
    {

        // Create token ticket
        FormsAuthenticationTicket tokenTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            appUser.Username,
            DateTime.Now,                
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(appUser.ExpiresIn),
            isPersistent,
            appUser.AccessToken);

        // Encrypt the ticket.
        string encTokenTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tokenTicket);

        // Create the cookie.
        HttpCookie tokenCookie = new HttpCookie("Mellon", encTokenTicket);
        tokenCookie.Secure = false;
        tokenCookie.Name = "Mellon";
        //tokenCookie.Path = Request.ApplicationPath;
        tokenCookie.Expires = tokenTicket.Expiration;

        return tokenCookie;
    }
}
```

I feel like questions will need to be asked of me to get the right info for help. I am just lost and at this point my tunnel vision is killing me. Any insight or hints or jsut some love at this point would help. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

This is where I check if cookie is still valid and perform a refresh if its still valid.

```
 protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        HttpCookie tokenCookie = Request.Cookies["Mellon"];

        if (authCookie == null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
            return;
        }

        // Extract the forms authentication cookie
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        if (authTicket == null || authTicket.Expired)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
            return;
        }

        // Extract the forms authentication cookie
        //FormsAuthenticationTicket newAuthTicket;

        if (tokenCookie == null)
        {
            RefreshCookies(authTicket);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket tokenTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(tokenCookie.Value);

            // If the access token is stil good, then continue on.
            if (tokenTicket.Expired)
            {
                RefreshCookies(authTicket);
                return;
            }
        }
        var tick = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        if (tick == null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
            return;
        }

        if (authTicket.UserData != tick.Ticket.UserData) // .Ticket.UserData)
        {
            RefreshCookies(authTicket);
        }

    }
```

Basically what I have is my AuthToken which holds me refresh token and a second cookie that holds me AccessToken. Those are created in the AuthenticateUserByService method which gets all that info from our webapi and is returned in response.AppUser. So I can't use forms.setauthcookie because that would overwrite what is already in there.

Image proof of whats going on:
[image: Now you see them]

[image: Now you dont]

Comment: Where's the logic that adds the user details to a claim(s)?

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: No worries, I'll post answer shortly but i'll break it up into smaller parts and will be a working solution. It's rather difficult to digest the snippets posted.

Comment: Thank you very much, and yeah I get that.

Comment: I'm still not sure where your adding the user details to claims?

Comment: Now I get what your saying, for some reason it didnt click the first time. Let me try something and ill get back to you shortly.

Comment: So something liek this :            newIdent.AddClaim(new Claim("Id", response.AppUser.Id.ToString()));
            newIdent.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, response.AppUser.Username));
            newIdent.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, response.AppUser.Id.ToString()));

?

Comment: Yes, play around with that and see how you get on.

Comment: Yeah I added that in, and i see it get added, but then when I check it again in the global.asax they are all gone.

Comment: Debug through each step/method too see if you can see anything amiss.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150869/discussion-between-darkwingduck-and-tez-wingfield).

Comment: Where you able to ever solve this?

Comment: I am in the middle of solving some problems at work, let me finish those up and I will see if I can't find what i did to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, it's rather tough to digest the snippets you have posted, So I'll break down into smaller logical chunks.

Let's start of with an `Authentication Service Class`:

Authentication Service calls the `client repository` and returns a `User`

```
 public class AuthenticationService
 {
    IUserRepository _userRepo;

    public AuthenticationService()
    {
      _userRepo = new UserRepository();
    }

    public User GetUser(string username, string password)
    {
       return _userRepo.FindByCredentials(username, password);
    }

   public User GetUserByUserName(string username)
    {
       return _userRepo.FindByUserName(username);
    }
 }
```

In the `Global.asax` we need to authenticate with pre-flight request.

```
      protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Check the request for a cookie
            var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                //Decrypt the Auth Cookie vale
                var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                //Instantiate Auth Service
                var _authService = new AuthenticationService();

                //Get user by encrypted name stored in ticket
                var user = _authService.GetUserByUserName(ticket.Name);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    // Create a ClaimsIdentity with all the claims for this user.

                    Claim emailClaim = new Claim("Email", (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Email)) ? user.Email: "");
                    Claim AddressClaim = new Claim("Address", (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Address)) ? user.Address: "");
                    Claim userNameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Username)) ? user.Username : "");

                   //Add claims to a collection of claims
                    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        emailClaim ,
                        AddressClaim ,
                        userNameClaim 
                    };

                   //Create forms Identity
                    FormsIdentity formsIdentity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);

                   //Create Claims Identity
                    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(formsIdentity);

                   //Add Claims
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaims(claims);

                   //Create Claims Principal
                    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

                    //Assign principal to current user
                    HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Login Controller:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    var user = _authService.GetUser(model.UserName, model.password);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName,model.RememberMe);
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);                    }
                    }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
```

As I've said this is a naïve attempt, please consider a little more security, but this is working sln I've quickly put together and I can access the claims.

Having looked at your code, it feels that your just missing adding the Claims of the user.

Comment: I am going to add my Application_AuthenticateRequest method to my original post. What you have here wont quite work for what I am trying to accomplish. I will see if I can update above with more on why.

Comment: Please feel free, may help generating answers from others too.

Comment: Yeah the more people ask the better I will be able to explain what is up. My grasp on this subject isn't great, and my abilities to explain suck.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening is the claims are getting overwritten in my global.asax. My fix so far has been to just rebuild my claims in my global.asax.