# Asp.net .ASPXAUTH cookie value always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Here I have a piece of code to make a cookie with the asp.net FormAuthenticationTicket. When I debug the code i find that the expiration date of the ticket is correct, but the expiration date of the cookie changes to 01/01/0001/12:00:000AM. Any idea why this happens?
Also, in the browser the name of the cookie is .ASPXAUTH, but the value is empty. So whenever we browse the webpage we get kicked out.

*Authentication class*

```
public class TicketAuth
{
    public HttpCookie Encrypt(string id)
    { 
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, id, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(3), false, "", FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        HttpCookie c = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
        return c;
    }

    public int Decrypt()
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
        int key = Convert.ToInt32(ticket.Name);
        return key;
    }
}
```

*controller*

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(Account account)
{
    TicketAuth ticket = new TicketAuth();
    HttpCookie c = ticket.Encrypt(account.Id.ToString());
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(c);
    if (account.Admin)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Accounts");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Bon", "Bon");
}
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468660/user-claims-seem-to-be-getting-replaced-somewhere-along-the-pipeline/45469964#45469964

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code with your Encrypt method

```
public HttpCookie Encrypt(string id)
{ 
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "someName", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(3), false, id, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    HttpCookie c = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
    return c;
}
```

you need to pass your serialized object as the 6th parameter in FormsAuthenticationTicket constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt()` requires that `ticket.Name`, `ticket.UserData` and `ticket.CookiePath` don't be null. In case of `ticket.UserData`, make sure at least to use `string.Empty` instead of null, for example.